# Remainder/Modulus of string is a number

Tags: javascript, string, type-conversion, modulus

Why is this even possible?

```
console.log('13' % 2);
```

`1`

I assume JavaScript just converts the string on its own. I would appreciate any info on this behaviour.

Comment: Whenever a mathematical operation is executed, its operands are coerced into numbers. If either cannot be, the result is `NaN`. If both can be, the operation completes and the value is returned. I think this is the related section in the ES5 spec: http://es5.github.io/#x11.5 . Basically says that `ToNumber` is used on each operand (`ToNumber` is just a pseudo method for what happens internally)

Comment: @Ian not all mathematical operations (see `+`)

Comment: @Nirk Well one could argue that if a string is included when using `+`, it isn't a mathematical operation :) But you're absolutely right, that is a great point and I shouldn't have said **all**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a starting point: http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.5

The `ToNumber` operation is performed on the left argument (which results in the left argument being treated as the number, as explained in http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3.1)