# String modulo Int from Javascript to Go

Tags: javascript, go, binary, int, modulo

I am trying to translate this code from Javascript to Go.

```
if(secret_binary % secret_alphabet_bitlength > 0) {
    secret_binary += zeropad("0", secret_alphabet_bitlength - (secret_binary % secret_alphabet_bitlength));
}
```

secret_binary is a `string` (representing a binary).
secret_alphabet_bitlength is an `int` (`6` to be precise).

Note : zeropad function is just adding the number of `0` needed. I replace it by the `for` loop that you can see below.

From what I understood in this topic [Remainder/Modulus of string is a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140073/remainder-modulus-of-string-is-a-number), the `ToNumber` is applied to the value that is not a string.

Fine, that is what I tried.

```
bToBig, _ := new(big.Int).SetString(secretBinary, 2)
nb := int64(secretAlphabetBitLength) - (bToBig.Int64() % int64(secretAlphabetBitLength))
if bToBig.Int64()%int64(secretAlphabetBitLength) > 0 {
    for i := 0; int64(i) < nb; i++ {
        secretBinary += "0"
    }
}
```

This `000001001100010000000001000111000001000000` is becoming `0000010011000100000000010001110000010000000000` for both the Javascript code and the Golang one. So it is "working", if I can say so.

But, this `001011001001000100001110000001010000010000000101000100000000000010011001000000010000001001010010000001010100000101010011000000` should become `0010110010010001000011100000010100000100000001010001000000000000100110010000000100000010010100100000010101000001010100110000000000` according to the Javascript code but here is what I get `00101100100100010000111000000101000001000000010100010000000000001001100100000001000000100101001000000101010000010101001100000000` (only two zeros are added instead of 4)

I do not know what to do, I tried to parse the string into INT, HEXA, BINARY, OCTAL, etc.. nothing work.

Comment: *"the ToNumber is applied to the value that is not a string."* You misunderstood, the linked answer states that ToNumber is applied to the *left* value. The left value is `'13'` a string.

Comment: @mkopriva : Ok, thanks. But in that case, it is "the same" right ? The string is converted into a Number.

Comment: You are interpreting the string in base 2 in Go, but in base 10 in JavaScript. Also, [Int.Int64](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Int64) says "if x cannot be represented in an int64, the result is undefined". Your number is much bigger than 64 bit in base 2.

Comment: @Peter : If I change `new(big.Int).SetString(value, 2)` from `2` to `10`, it is not working for the first example (that is working with base 2), any `0` is added whereas `4` should be added.

Comment: You are dealing with numbers that are much bigger than 64 bit here. Who knows what JavaScript does with that (I seem to remember that you can only use 32 bits accurately, but these numbers are too big in any case). You are trying to replicate JavaScript's undefined behaviour in Go. That's just futile.

Comment: @Peter : I am trying, the best I can, to translate a code of a very permissive langage into Go. I perfectly know that I am not on the right direction, this is why I need help here, I just discovered `math/big` when trying to translate it.

Comment: @Peter : I also took a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin and even if I understand the limitation, I can't stop thinking that there should be a way to get the same result from one langage to another.

Comment: There is no single solution that always works, because what JS does is implementation dependent. For instance, [parseInt](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-parseint-string-radix) says, "if [the radix] is 10 and [your number string] contains more than 20 significant digits, every significant digit after the 20th may be replaced by a 0 digit, at the option of the implementation". So you really have to figure out what your JS engine does and replicate that in Go. You won't find matching functions in the standard library.

Comment: @Peter : Thanks, I get it now. I will take a look at the global view of the script to see if I can implement this little function in another way. Maybe it works for him in JS but it is totally lucky